# Confusion: gitlab-runner register image and gitlab-ci.yml image

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

What is the relationship of the gitlab-runner image, given on registration and the image given in the gitlab-ci?

I have registered a gitlab-runner with:

`gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --executor "docker" --docker-image "ubuntu:latest" [...]`

This is my CI:

```
job:
  image: alpine:3.7
  script: ...
```

Will now alpine be run inside of ubuntu? Sounds weird.

Is the `--docker-image` parameter of gitlab-runner just defining a default image?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's the default image as mentioned here: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#docker

So instead of the default ubuntu image the alpine image given by the CI job will be run.